# $|\nabla \omega|^2= \alpha \omega^n+ \beta$ - References

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

I'm interested to know if anyone can give me some information (name, references, etc.) about this PDE 
$$|\nabla \omega|^2= \alpha \omega^n+ \beta,$$ 
where $\omega$ is a scalar function of two or more variables, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are arbitrary constants $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I do not understand it. From the equation you get that $\omega=(-\beta/\alpha)^{1/n}$ is constant. There must be a mistake in your statement.

Comment: @Piotr Hajlasz - Yes, there was a mistake, thank you!

Comment: It looks like an eikonal equation with a nonlinear wave speed; that's what I would search for anyway as a start.

Comment: @Willie Wong - Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually, can you not transform this into a standard eikonal equation? If you let $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a primitive of $(\alpha z^n + \beta)^{-\frac12}$, then your equation is equivalent to $|\nabla F(\omega)| = 1$ which is the standard eikonal equation.

Comment: @Willie Wong - thank you very much for the suggestion but unfortunately I can not transform it

Comment: In that case, it may be worthwhile to include in your question some discussion of where this equation comes from and why you cannot do the nonlinear change of variables that I suggested, to get a more targeted response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86450/discussion-between-alexander-pigazzini-and-willie-wong).